If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n$ converges uniformly, then each $g_n$ is bounded by a real number $M_n$.
$\textbf{Question}:$If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, is it true that each $g_n(x)$ is bounded by a real number $M_n$?
This question came into my mind because when I was doing my homework, I saw a problem that required each $g_n$ to be bounded when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ converges uniformly.
Does that mean that there exists some counter-example s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ converges uniformly, but not every $g_n$ is bounded?
The thing I know is that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $0$, but then I have no idea. Any hints will be helpful, thanks in advance.

You are right that $(g_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$, and that implies that the functions are eventually bounded: For $\epsilon = 1$ there is an index $N$ such that $|g_n(x)| < \epsilon = 1$ for all $n \ge N$ and all $x \in A$.
One can not conclude that all functions are bounded: Take $A= (0, 1)$, $g_1(x) = 1/x$ and $g_n(x) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$. Then $\sum g_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $1/x$ on $A$, but $g_1$ is not bounded.
Similarly one can construct examples where arbitrary (but finitely) many of the $g_n$ are unbounded, but $\sum g_n$ is still uniformly convergent.
